# What character is this?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program to generate a box with a user-defined sidelength and border/fill characters. Everything is working as I want it to, except when it prints the box to the terminal, it produces a strange character I cannot find anywhere. I feel like if I know what it is, I might be able to fix it. My header file is here:

```
#ifndef Box_h
#define Box_h

class Box
{
private:
    int pSidelength;
    char pBorder;
    char pFill;

public:
    Box(int pSidelength, char pBorder = '#', char pFill = '*');
    int Sidelength;
    char Border;
    char Fill;

    int Area();
    int Perimeter();
    int GetSize();
    int Grow();
    int Shrink();

    char SetBorder();
    char SetFill();

    void Draw();
    void Summary();
};
#endif Box_h
```

My source for the class is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "box.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

Box::Box(int pSidelength, char pBorder, char pFill)
{
    if (pSidelength < 1)
        {
            Sidelength = 1;
        }
    else if (pSidelength > 39)
        {
            Sidelength = 39;
        }
    else
    {
        Sidelength = pSidelength;
    }
    if (pBorder != '#')
    {
        SetBorder();
    }
    if (pFill != '*')
    {
        SetFill();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Box     MyBox1(3,'#','*');
    Box     MyBox2(7, '^', '*');
    Box     MyBox3(10, '$', '%');
    MyBox1.Grow();
    MyBox2.Shrink();

    MyBox1.Summary();
    MyBox2.Summary();
    MyBox3.Summary();

    return 0;
    }

int Box::Shrink()
{
    if (Sidelength == 1)
        {
            Sidelength = Sidelength;
        }
    else
        {
            Sidelength = Sidelength - 1;
        }
    return Sidelength;
} 

int Box::Grow()
{
     if (Sidelength == 39)
        {
            Sidelength = Sidelength;
        }
    else
        {
            Sidelength = Sidelength + 1;
        }
    return Sidelength;
}

char Box::SetFill()
{
Fill = pFill;
    return Fill;
}

char Box::SetBorder()
{
    Border = pBorder;
    return Border;
}

int Box::Area()
{
    int area = (Sidelength)*(Sidelength);
    return area;
}

int Box::Perimeter()
{
    int perimeter = 4 * (Sidelength);
    return perimeter;
}

int Box::GetSize()
{
    int size = Sidelength;
    return size;
}

void Box::Draw()
{
int j = 1;
int k = 1;

if (Sidelength == 1 || Sidelength == 2)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= Sidelength; i++)
    {
        while (j <= Sidelength)
        {
            cout << setw(2) << Border;
            j++;
        }
        j = 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
else
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= Sidelength; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == Sidelength)
            {
                while (k <= Sidelength)
                {
                    cout << setw(2) << Border;
                    k++;
                }
                cout << endl;
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                while (j <= Sidelength)
                {
                    if (j == 1 || j == Sidelength)
                    {
                        cout << setw(2) << Border;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << setw(2) << Fill;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                cout << endl;
                j = 1;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Box::Summary()
    {
    cout << "The Sidelength of the box is: " << Box::GetSize() << endl;
    cout << "The Perimeter of the box is: " << Box::Perimeter() << endl;
    cout << "The Area of the box is: " << Box::Area() << endl;
    Box::Draw();
    }
```

The program has a default character associated with Border/Fill, as specified in the header file. When run, it produces this:

[image: Terminal Output]

What character is that, and any ideas on why it would be appearing in the first place?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]  eg in your code above `Box::SetBorder()` is never called.

Comment: Yes it is, in the constructor for the box. If the parameter passed in for Border/Fill is not a space, it calls SetBorder/SetFill to assign a value to the public variables Border/Fill.

Comment: `SetBorder` is called, but it doesn't set the value of `pBorder`, which is where your bogus character is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character is random, and could in theory be different every time you run the program.

It's coming from the `pBorder` member, which is never set to anything.

Comment: I changed the default character to #/* for border and fill (respectively) and still get the same output. To reiterate, they both now have a default value which is not a space and still produce that character.

Comment: @GrahamWilson What do you mean, default character? The `pBorder` member of your box object isn't set anywhere.

Comment: pBorder/pFill are initialized to #/* in the header file.

Comment: @GrahamWilson, please add that part of the code as well

Comment: @GrahamWilson No, that's the constructor parameter `pBorder` you're talking about (and that one is set but never used). We're talking about the class member `pBorder`. They're different variables.

Comment: @GrahamWilson: Be aware that you have two variables called `pBorder`; one is a parameter to the constructor, and one is a member variable.  It's the member variable that's being used but not initialised.

Comment: @GrahamWilson It is not enough that you have defaults for the constructor **parameters**, you simply don't use these parameters other than comparing them to their defaults. They have zero connection to your `Border` variable that you use to actually draw your box, which again is distinct from the `pBorder` member variable that you have declared private (which is also not set!)..

Comment: I added another variable to store the value passed in, then assigned that value to pBorder, and everything works as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You got confused with same name of variables.

```
Box::Box(int pSidelength, char pBorder, char pFill)
{
    if (pSidelength < 1)
        {
            Sidelength = 1;
        }
    else if (pSidelength > 39)
        {
            Sidelength = 39;
        }
    else
    {
        Sidelength = pSidelength;
    }
    if (pBorder != ' ') //Here pBorder has '*' but this is local 
//                        pBorder to this Function
    {
        SetBorder();
    }
    if (pFill != ' ')
    {
        SetFill();
    }
}
```

And When you call `SetBorder();`

It makes `Border` as `pBorder` as that was declared in the class which is still unintialized.

```
char Box::SetBorder()
{
    Border = pBorder; //This pBorder is not initialized
    return Border;
}
```

> Solution 1

Dont use Function

```
if (pBorder != ' ') 

{
    Border = pBorder;
}
```

> Solution 2

Pass pBorder

```
if (pBorder != ' ') 

{
    SetBorder(pBorder);
}
char Box::SetBorder(char pBorder)
{
    Border = pBorder; //This pBorder is not initialized
    return Border;
}
```

Comment: No, reading an initialized variable is still wrong, even if you set it after.